# Installed python package gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, module, pip, package

I pushed a package to pypip and then installed it successfully.
Since i'm on anaconda I can do `conda list` and confirm my package is installed in the base environment.

Next I want to use it:

```
from epicprint import Print
```

But this throws a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'epicprint'

I assume I have some error in my package structure. It does work in my test.py file which is odd. Please see the files in the package repo below:

#### Print.py

```
import os
import sys

# Glorious print with color and grouping
class Print(object):
    ...
```

#### __init __.py

```
from Print import Print
```

#### setup.py

```
import setuptools
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
setuptools.setup(
     name='epicprint',  
     version='0.1',
     author="abc",
     author_email="abc@abc.com",
     description="Custom print with superpowers",
     url="https://github.com/ajthinking/print",
     packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
     classifiers=[
         "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
         "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
         "Operating System :: OS Independent",
     ],
 )
```

#### test.py

```
from Print import Print

print = Print()

print.info("Welcome").group()
print.success("Now we can:", ["Indent stuff", "Use colors", "Attach semantic to the print statements"])
print.warning("Nothing more to say")
print.reset().fail("Ending with a fail message. Bye.")
```

All the files are in the root of the repo except one .whl and one .tar.gz found in the dist folder plus the build and egg-info folders after running the setup script.

```
├── LICENSE
├── Print.py
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── Print.cpython-37.pyc
├── build
│   └── bdist.macosx-10.7-x86_64
├── dist
│   ├── epicprint-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── epicprint-0.1.tar.gz
├── epicprint.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── setup.py
└── test.py
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is your directory structure if there any subdirectories?

Comment: @phd question is now updated with directory structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any package directory (a subdirectory with `__init__.py`), so `setuptools.find_packages()` returns an empty list, so your distributions don't contain and don't install any python modules or packages.

Either you install `Print.py` as a standalone module:

```
setuptools.setup(
    …
    # packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    py_modules=['Print.py'],
    …
)
```

Or move `Print.py` and `__init__.py` into a subdirectory `epicprint/` then `setuptools.find_packages()` returns `['epicprint']` package and the distributions will catch it.

In the latter case your `test.py` must be adapted:

```
from epicprint.Print import Print
```

Whether you want `test.py` in `epicprint/` package is up to you.